# Check a checkbox based on variable

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I'm trying to create an inventory form that starts with a single item checked based on a variable passed from the URL.

Assuming I've gotten the variable here:
    `$StartingInv = $_GET["SInv"];`

And that variable, if present, will perfectly match the value of one of a list of inputs like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="inventory" name="order[]" value="IT1501"><label>Item IT1501 Name</label><br/>
<input type="checkbox" class="inventory" name="order[]" value="IT1502"><label>Item IT1502 Name</label><br/>
```

Is there some way to compare the value of an input to a variable when the page is loaded to programmatically assign a "checked" tag?

What I'd like to do is have a script that gets the input by it's value and assigns a checked tag, but I don't know if that's possible.

Alternatively, I could put something like this into each of the inputs, but I don't know how to reference it.

`<?php if ($VALUE_OF_THIS_FORM == $StartingInv) echo "checked='checked'"; ?>`

Comment: Your last line is spot on, this seems like something you could easily do serverside without any javascript at all.

Comment: `<input type="checkbox"<?= $val == "something" ? " checked" : "" ?>>`

Comment: yes its correct u can use below 
<input type="checkbox" class="inventory" name="order[]" value="IT1501" <?php if ('IT1501' == $StartingInv) echo "checked='checked'"; ?> ><label>Item IT1501 Name</label><br/>
<input type="checkbox" class="inventory" name="order[]" value="IT1502" <?php if ('IT1502' == $StartingInv) echo "checked='checked'"; ?> ><label>Item IT1502 Name</label><br/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can place the php code inside your input:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="inventory" name="order[]" value="IT1501" <?php if($StartingInv == 'IT1501') echo 'checked'; ?>> <label>Item IT1501 Name</label><br/>
<input type="checkbox" class="inventory" name="order[]" value="IT1502" <?php if($StartingInv == 'IT1502') echo 'checked'; ?>><label>Item IT1502 Name</label><br/>
```

Comment: This is basically what I did, but I wrote a PHP function which takes a single identifier and generates this line.

Answer (score 0):

Your alternative is good enough, which is backed up by @adeneo on the comments. However, you could also try jQuery for this like so:

```
var startingInv = "<?= $StartingInv ?>";
$(":checkbox").each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == startingInv) $(this).prop("checked", true);
}
```